# Update FieldA with Substring of FieldB

Tags: mysql, sql-update

Newbie warning (yes I looked for answer):

I have a substring query to get first word from FieldA

SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX( `field` , ' ', 1 ) AS `field_first_word`
FROM `your_table`

and am trying to write that to FieldB

update yourtable set fieldB = (above string)

doing an update tells me I can't use yourtable in the from command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your expression on `FieldA` directly within the `SET` clause of the `UPDATE` command:

```
UPDATE your_table SET FieldB = SUBSTRING_INDEX(FieldA, ' ', 1)
```